# How to cross out text in Windows 7 Sticky Notes app?

Tags: windows-7

Would like to *strike out* items in Sticky Notes instead of *deleting* them, so as to know the items that were completed along with items to be completed.

Answer (score 0):

**Highlight** the text and Use **CTRL+T**

[Reference](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/is-it-possible-to-cross-out-items-in-sticky-notes/b804d8dd-1bca-4c4f-b77a-1a6549a1eadd)